# How to export columns into a Word document in Google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For example: I would like to take A, C, D columns of a spreadsheet named workstuff into a separate Word file.

How would one do that? Let's say that they are in range 4:200.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script with comments:

```
function sample() {
  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("documentId"); // open spreadsheet
  let sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("sheetTabName"); // get the tab
  let values = sheet.getRange("A4:D200").getValues(); // load A, B, C and D
  values = values.map(row => [row[0], row[2], row[3]]); // remove B
  values = values.map(row => row.map(cell => '' + cell)); // convert to string

  let doc = DocumentApp.create("my-new-document"); // create new document
  doc.getBody().appendTable(values); // write values into table in the document
  doc.saveAndClose(); // Save and close it

  // Convert google document to word document
  let token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var docBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=' + doc.getId() + '&exportFormat=docx',
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
      }
    }).getBlob();

  // save word document it on drive
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(docBlob).setName('my-new-document.docx');
  DriveApp.addFile(file);
}
```

You may get the spreadsheet ID from url like:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SJKf90ahisfq8ewfyio32jasf890sadj3/edit#gid=4531234
```

The ID is: `SJKf90ahisfq8ewfyio32jasf890sadj3`

Comment: Code works! Thank you! But i was also wondering if i could seperate different rows based on the cell value of one specific column. For example: while the C collumns cell is "Technology" input that row into the document, else go to the next row. Should i use a for loop in this instance?

Comment: The ```values``` is a array (rows) of arrays (columns)... You need to manipulate it to build your data before write it to the ```doc```. You may write other things  and not only tables to it.